# SQL aggregate query with one-to-many relationship with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to aggregate a list of product skus with a query that relates through a line_items table. I've abstracted a simple example of my use case:

**my expected result would look like this:**

```
id  name        skus
1   mike bar    sku1,sku2,sku3
2   bort baz    sku4
```

given a schema and data like:

products

```
id  sku
1   sku1
2   sku2
3   sku3 
4   sku4
```

line_items

```
id  order_id    product_id
1   1           1
2   1           2
3   1           3
4   2           4
```

addresses

```
id  name
1   'bill foo'
2   'mike bar'
3   'bort baz'
```

orders

```
id  address_id  total
1   2           66
2   3           99
```

here's a working query, but it's not correct, i'm getting ALL products for each order. my `WHERE` should be using `orders.id`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70cd7/3/0

however, i can't seem to use `orders.id`? i'm guessing i need to use a `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` or somehow change the order of things in my query...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70cd7/4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery with a `JOIN` to get the list of `sku`s for each `order`

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    a.name,
    (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(sku), ',') AS Skus
     FROM products p
     INNER JOIN line_items li
        ON li.product_id = p.id
     WHERE li.order_id = o.id
    ) AS Skus
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN addresses a
  ON a.id = o.address_id
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70cd7/6/0)</kbd>

Comment: `array_to_string(array_agg(..), ..)` can be replaced with `string_agg()`

Answer (score 8):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70cd7/12

```
SELECT orders.id,
       addresses.name,
       array_agg(DISTINCT products.sku )
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN addresses
ON orders.address_id = addresses.id
LEFT JOIN line_items
ON line_items.order_id = orders.id
LEFT JOIN  products
ON products.id = line_items.product_id
GROUP BY orders.id,addresses.name
```

Comment: Your solution is very good because is optimized and solved my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be

```
SELECT orders.id,
   addresses.name,
   (SELECT string_agg(sku,',') AS skus
    FROM products
    WHERE id IN
       (SELECT DISTINCT line_items.product_id
        FROM line_items
        WHERE line_items.order_id = orders.id))
FROM orders
inner join addresses
on orders.address_id = addresses.id
;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70cd7/16)